# Is there a way to enforce a specific string structure for a Postgres column?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a field in a database that is a string of the form XXXYYXXXX where the Xs are numbers and the Ys are letters -- is there a way to define the table such that trying to insert a new row where this field fails to match causes an error?

I'd know how to do this if I was working with the DB through an ORM, but haven't had to do validation like this in pure SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) using a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), e.g.:

```
create table my_table(
    id serial primary key, 
    str text check (str ~ '^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}$')
);

insert into my_table values
(default, 'abc99def')
returning *;

 id |   str    
----+----------
  1 | abc99def
(1 row)

insert into my_table values
(default, '1bc99def')
returning *;

ERROR:  new row for relation "my_table" violates check constraint "my_table_str_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1bc99def).
```